# why do we lein both rishon and sheini of ki savo on monday/thursday/shabbos mincha?

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, ki-tavo, bikkurim-first-fruits, parsha

i would assume it is to be able to link the parshios of bikurim and vidui maaser due to their similarities, but would like to see a source inside for it. thanks!

Comment: Someone pointed out to me that the Monday-Thursday readings for much of Sefer Devarim are unusually long.

Comment: Not all communities do this. Some just read "rishon", splitting for the third aliyah at ויביאנו.

Comment: It seems more plausible to me that those who have the practice you mention are trying not to split up the bikkurim reading since it is one long quote.